# AngularJS 1.4 ng-repeat broken (works outside of our app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a small directive that allows a user to select the size/amount of pills he would like to order (image bellow).

When a user clicks on the selected size I replace the selected object used for the pill list with a new object. As you can see ng-repeat is quite slow and actually draws twice, first time includes both objects (old and new one).

I can't reproduce bug outside of our application.
Code is quite simple:

```
    $scope.selectDosage = function(newDosage) {
      $scope.selectedDosage = _.find($scope.product.dosages, {dosage: newDosage});
    };
```

I've added logging, but it seems the JS execution is fast (object is quite small) so this has to be an AngularJS problem related with how the app was built.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before? Any ideas where I can start looking? I've not built the app and making very slow progress.

--- Some updates from my investigation ---

Added a bit of logging:

```
1474974036140 " - CLICK FIRED"
digest
1474974036156 " - WATCH CHANGED"
new val -  3
old val -  4
```

What we are seeing is the time of the click and when the object selectedDosage change (using $scope.$watch). There's a single digest cycle that is fired (I've added logging in AngularJS, no additional digest cycles are triggered) and the new values (length of array of pill sizes, old vs new) which seems fine.

No closer to an answer though

[image]

Comment: I feel I would start by setting a $watch on "selectedDosage" so you can see when it is changed - it looks like it is briefly set to the full list before being filtered.  Once your watch handler is capturing it you could attach a debugger to see where that is coming from.

Comment: I'm doing that as we speak (well write) but no bright insights as of now

Comment: @GuyNesher, I think you would have to put up a working example so the community can help you.

Comment: @NicolasGaller - theres a 5ms difference between click and watch being triggered. values (old and new) are correct - not an accumulated value.

Comment: @Maximus - I can't replicate the bug outside of my application and sharing the entire application code base is just not an option. I'm hoping someone has encountered a similar problem